# Are high density buildings larger on avenues than for streets?

Tags: simcity-2013

I notice that the guidelines for avenues are further apart when placing avenues than when placing streets. Does this mean that the high density buildings for avenues are larger? Or does it take into account the fact that avenues are wider?

It just seems that the spacing between the avenues is too wide, even after accounting for the double width of an avenue compared to a street.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are the same size.

The road spacing for two high density zones is exactly two Wavy-Tree parks lengthwise.

http://www.reddit.com/r/SimCityStrategy/comments/1a0zat/35_using_roads_and_avenues_in_harmony/